# Коммерческое использование библиотеки

Tags: java, android, github, лицензирование

Могу ли я использовать [Данную библиотеку](https://github.com/spacecowboy/NoNonsense-FilePicker) в своём Android приложении, в коммерческих целях?

Comment: Там же указана лицензия - https://github.com/spacecowboy/NoNonsense-FilePicker/blob/master/LICENSE. Просто нужно её прочитать. Тем более возможно её могут заменить потом на другую.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Речь идет о лицензии [Mozilla Public License Version 2.0](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/MPL/2.0/)

Это довольно специфическая лицензия, суть которой сводится к:

1. Вы можете использовать продукт - как часть другого продукта, в т.ч. коммерческого, при условии, если в работе приводите текст лицензии.
2. Если модифицируете исходники (библиотеки в данном контексте), то должны опубликовать полные тексты библиотеки с той же самой лицензией.

Краткий перечень чего можно и нельзя [приведен здесь](https://tldrlegal.com/license/mozilla-public-license-2.0-(mpl-2))